# How to interpret the radioactivity for a radioactive material that generate isotopes?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I have a Strontium-90 radioactive source. The radioactivity of this source is $0.1\mu\ \rm Ci$.

This source $\beta$−decays into Yttrium-90. Then Yttrium-90  $\beta$−decays into Zirconium-90 with a half-life of $64.1$ hours.

My question is when they write that Strontium-90 has $0.1\mu\ \rm Ci$ radioactivity, does that exclude the activity of Yttrium-90? (I mean do they some how calculate the activity of Strontium-90 decay to Yttrium-90 alone, without the activity of Yttrium-90 decaying to Zirconium-90?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One curie is $3.7 \times 10^{10}$ decays per second, so it is not a measure of the amount of energy emitted. It is just a measure of how many strontium nuclei decay per second.

So your $0.1 \mu\textrm{Ci}$ source has $3.7 \times 10^{3}$ strontium nuclei per second decaying. It does not count the numbers of yttrium nuclei decaying. In practice the number of strontium and yttrium decays per second is virtually identical since the half life of yttrium is so much shorter than the half life of strontium.

The two decays have different energies so they can be distinguished to some extent, though because beta electrons have a continuous distribution of energies the two energy distributions overlap.